# Do we need to set a process variable to null in a finally block?

Tags: java, process

If we have the following code:

```
Process p = null;
BufferedReader br = null;

try{
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -ef");
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    //Do something with br
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Handle catch block
} finally {
    //Do we need to set p = null;
}
```

Is the p = null required in a finally block or all the associated streams are closed by default?

Comment: At a guess, I'd suspect the answer might be "neither": setting `p = null` would not have any effect on the associated streams.

Comment: irrespective of you set null or not, it is always better to close any open Streams .

Comment: +1 Always close the stream, but very good question relating to closing/destroying process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no need to set the process to `null`, but it'd be a good idea to explicitly close the `BufferedReader` in the `finally` block. Or even better, if using Java 7 or above, consider using [`try` with resources](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to automatically close the stream.

Answer (score 2):

Since you must consume the entire `InputStream` of the process in order to prevent blocking, once you have done that there will be no great difference whether you explicitly close the reader or not. After the process is dead, the input stream closes and the wrapper readers turn into garbage. They don't engage any other system resources and thus are harmless.

Setting a variable which references the `Process` instance is of no consequence.

Answer (score 0):

Setting null is not mandatory, but you should call `p.destroy()` method in finally.

This Kills the subprocess. The subprocess represented by this Process object is forcibly terminated.

You can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

Cheers !!

Comment: There is an exitValue() function on Process too. I think it would be better to check if this is 0 in the finally block before doing a forcible termination using destroy().